# How to enter data for multiple cases simultaneously in SPSS?

Tags: categorical-data, spss

I need to add a new variable to an already existing datafile in SPSS. However, this is a categorical (dichotomous) variable and I have over 30,000 cases, therefore I was wondering if it is possible to enter the same value (i.e. either 0 or 1) for a large number of cases at the same time, so I don't need to enter the data for every individual case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some logical criteria for the values, just use an IF statement.  Or if most of the cases get one of the values, do COMPUTE x=1, say, and then correct the others.  Or create a new dataset with just this variable and then use MATCH FILES to add it to the main dataset.  Or, if you have a list of case numbers or id's that should get each value, read this with Python code and generate the necessary values.

Whatever you do, avoid manually entering 30,000 values: the error rate will inevitably be terrible.

If you explain the situation further, we can give more specific advice.